# How to capture and broadcast MJPEG stream from an IP webcam

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mjpeg, ip-camera

I've purchased a Foscam FI8910W IP webcam which outputs a live video stream in MJPEG format, and I'm trying to embed the live stream in a webpage.

I've already accomplished this goal by simply using the camera feed's URL as the source for an HTML img tag. The problem with this is that each browser session accessing this page connects to the camera, so the limited bandwidth that the camera has is quickly used up, so no more than 2 or 3 users can view the page at the same time.

What I would like to do is set up some sort of streaming server to access the camera's feed directly, and reproduce/process it in some way so that when users browse to my site they are pulling from the server rather than the camera.

Ideally this would be done without the need for any browser plugins, and would work across any browser. I'm pretty experienced in several programming languages, so writing something to handle this is not totally out of the question, I just don't have the slightest idea how to get started.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am trying to embed a mjpeg stream from a Raspberry Pi into my website. So what i’d like to do is stream the Raspberry Pi data to a server on the web and then have the server stream to web clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two options (both work for me):

1) C/C++ code + libjpeg library(use version above 8 since older ones exchange result only through file system). [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C) is a very nice article which I used to understand mjpeg and create C/C++ application that works.

- Pros: you have full control over the features you want
- Cons: a lot of coding/debugging/testing

2) gstreamer. It comes with a lot of plugins that you can utilize by carefully chosen command line. Look [here](http://moozing.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/gstreamer-and-mjpeg/) for example.

- Pros: no coding needed, just find suitable plugin and configure it
- Cons: might not answer all your requirements; potential comercial license issue

Answer (score 0):

Try [sourceforge webcamflv](http://sourceforge.net/p/webcamflv/wiki/Home/)
This is not maintained!..still works as expected!(if you can chose FLV over MJPEG stream )